# WMI query to capture Interactive logon event for permanent consumer

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm a powershell newbie and I want to create a filter to capture the login of a human user. Looking at the documentation out there the most popular WMI query seems to be:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 15 WHERE TargetInstance
ISA 'Win32_LogonSession' AND TargetInstance.LogonType = 2
```

This doesn't appear to work and I believe that an interactive logon should be of type 0 not 2. However, that still doesn't seem to work. Is there any filter you guys & gals know of that works?

Comment: `2` is correct for interactive logons. If users are logging in via Remote Desktop or similar terminal services, `LogonType` will be `10`

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394189(v=vs.85).aspx) just as you stated, interactive logon appears to be the value of 2.

With PowerShell you could query using something like the following:

If you are unsure of what version you have run `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` and look at the Major version.

**Powershell Version 2 or Below**

```
Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_LogonSession' | Where {$_.LogonType -eq '2'}
```

**PowerShell Version 3 or Above**

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_LogonSession' | Where {$_.LogonType -eq '2'}
```

Based on [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394189(v=vs.85).aspx) you could query by any of these:

> 2 = Interactive
>
> 3 = Network
>
> 4 = Batch
>
> 5 = Service
>
> 6 = Proxy
>
> 7 = Unlock
>
> 8 = NetworkClearText
>
> 9 = NewCredentials
>
> 10 = RemoteInteractive
>
> 11 = CachedInteractive
>
> 12 = CachedRemoteInteractive
>
> 13 = CachedUnlock

If you wanted to query for multiple logon types you could change the where statement to something like:

```
Where {$_.LogonType -in ('2','10','11','12')}
```

Hope this helps.